# pyinstaller exclude-module causes "failed to execute script"

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller

I'm creating an exe out of my simple script in command prompt with:
pyinstaller --onefile --exclude-module scipy myscript.py

and when I open the .exe I get a message that says "failed to run myscript.exe script"

but the thing is the program works perfectly fine when I don't use exclude-module..
it also works perfectly fine with or without scipy (I only added it in to learn the exclude-module command)

here is my .spec file that was generated by pysinstaller:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['Simpletkinter.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\Scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=['scipy'],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Simpletkinter',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

I plan to use the exclude option in the future so any help would be much appreciated!

Jared

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found out what the problem was...
You cannot use "import scipy" in your script and then later try to exclude it from pyinstaller.

I found a way around it where I only include modules inside each of my functions (which are all saved/organized in one file and used for any program I make)

now I can go and use:

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module scipy
```

which will successfully remove scipy since it is only listed inside a function which is not being used for the current script i'm trying to convert to EXE

Also I see now that python only imports once even if you tell it to import multiple times so this shouldn't slow down my programs even if I keep calling functions that import the same module multiple times